# Break a fixed-percentage-width-image out of a container and keep text aligned to left of that container

Tags: css, css-grid

What I would like to achieve is to have a fixed-percentage-width-image pop-out of a max-width'ed container when keeping the textblock aligned to the left of the max-widht'ed container.

What I want => [view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U1zL.png)

(I've set the max-width of the container to 300px instead of 1200px for better viewing purposes here on stackoverflow.) 
So I need the green text to be aligned to the left of the purple text BUT on the condition that the gray image always stays 40% of the viewport width.

Thanks in advance!

See pen =>

```css
.c-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(0, 300px) 1fr; // 300px as max-width of the container instead of 1200px for clear viewing purposes here on stackoverflow
  grid-template-rows: 48px;
}

.c-container__item {
  grid-column: 2;
  background-color: #FF00FF;
}

.c-content-block {
  grid-template-rows: 48px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0px, 1fr) minmax(0px, 1200px) 40%;
}

.c-content-block__item {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;

}

.c-content-block__item--content {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-container">
  <div class="c-container__item">
    some content inside container
  </div>
</div>

<div class="c-content-block">
  <div class="content-block__item c-content-block__item--content">
    ---> how can I align this text with the purple container?
  </div>
  <div class="c-content-block__item c-content-block__item--image" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1920x1280');">
    this image always needs to be 40% of the viewport width
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found the solution myself but with the help of position: absolute; on the image div so it stretches from top of the grid to bottom.

Maybe someone can advise in wether or not there is a CSS-Grid "only" solution without having to use position: absolute;?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(32px, 1fr) minmax(0,1200px) minmax(32px, 1fr);
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}
.item--container{
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  background-color: #FF00FF;
  margin-right: 40vw;
}
.item {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  background-color: #1098ad;
  color: #fff;
  justify-self: end;
  width: 40vw;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.item--normal{
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  background-color: #FF00FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item--normal">
    test
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item--container">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    This item "breaks the grid
  </div>
</div>
```